# NoMethodError undefined method 'each' fir nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I'm facing  NoMethodError in NewFormsController#create, undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass !

Here is my code :

**Controller : new_forms_controller.rb**

```
class NewFormsController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @form = NewForm.new
end

  def create
    @form = NewForm.new(params[:form])
    if @form.valid?
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created recommendation."
      redirect_to 'new_forms/new'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

**Model : new_form.rb**

```
class NewForm
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :titleID, :articleID, :content, :author

  validates :titleID, :articleID, :content, :author, :presence => true
  validates :titleID, :articleID => {:minimum => 5 }

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

**New View : new.html.erb**

```
<%= content_for :title, "New Article Form" %>

<%= form_for @form do |f| %>

    <% @form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <p><%= msg %></p>
    <% end %>

    <p>
      <%= f.label :titleID %> <br/>
      <%= f.text_field :titleID %><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :articleID %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :articleID %><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :content %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :content %><br/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :author %><br/>
      <%= f.text_field :author %><br/>
    </p>

    <p><%= f.submit "Submit"  %></p>
<% end %>
```

**Routes : routes.rb**

```
TestBranch::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :new_forms
  root :to => "new_forms#new"
end
```

I'm trying to implement ActiveModel because I don't want my form object to be backed up by database, I will have different service for database interactions.

Comment: I'm still getting this error when I click on Submit button, It doesnt show any errors or anything. I'm following this railcast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Comment: Try including `ActiveModel::Errors` in your `NewForm` class.

Comment: Getting NoMethodError in New_forms#new
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #3):

    `1: <%= content_for :title, "New Form" %>`  `2:`  `3: <%= form_for @form do |f| %>`  `4: `  `5:     <% @form.errors.messages.each do |msg| %>`  `6:         <p><%= msg %></p>`

Answer (score 0):

it seems your model is correct and doens't include errors, so `@form.errors` contains `[]`

you could check for errors

```
<% @form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p><%= msg %></p>
<% end unless @form.errors.blank? %>
```

update from my comments:

please try `params[:new_form]` instead of `params[:form]`. your identifier `:form` is wrong. your model called `NewForm` so your param name is `new_form`

Comment: It's not working. I even tried removing error showing part but then it's throwing NewFormsController#create, but create action doesnt have any .each statement in it.

Comment: ah. then `attributes` in `NewForm#initiliaze` looks empty. what does `params` include? does `params[:form]` really contains data?

Comment: I'm a newbie. I was just following this railcast : http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model , params[:form] is supposed to recieve data from the form submit. 
Tell me if I'm missing something. I'm just trying to implement this form which is not associated to any db but still validations can be performed on it.

Comment: ok. please try `params[:new_form]` instead of `params[:form]`. your identifier `:form` is wrong. your model called `NewForm` so your param name is `new_form`

Comment: Hey, that worked. Not getting .each error now. But I'm getting   TypeError in NewFormsController#new  wrong argument type Class (expected Module)

Comment: It was due to include ActiveModel::Errors! I removed it and it's working fine.

Comment: Can you tell me how to output the fields entered int the form. Right now what I'm trying is 
`if @form.valid?`  
`redirect_to 'new_forms/:form'`  and in my show view, I'm using @form.members to access them, But it's redirecting me to "The connection was reset" page.

Comment: @AmanMehra thats another question. please ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 <% if @forms.errors.any? %>
   <% @form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <p><%= msg %></p>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: It is `@form` not `@forms`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<% if @form.errors.any? %>
 <% @form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p><%= msg %></p>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```